# Audio play in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```html
<audio id="audio" controls> 
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="https://my-app-domain.com/uploads/2021/03/model-audio1614939065612file732.mp3"> </source>
</audio>
```

The above code snipped is from my app. I need to test the audio is playable with cypress.

Below is my code to play the audio:

```js
cy.visit('/');
cy.get("source")
  .invoke("src")
  .then((audiofile) => {
    const audio = new Audio(audiofile);
    audio.play();
  });
```

With the above code I get the following error.

[image]

How can I test play audio with cypress ?

Comment: Remember that Cypress is still bound to the modern browser's "autoplay is not allowed until there's page interaction", so click somewhere on the page or something before calling play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The following code block got the job done for me.

```js
      cy.get('source')
      .invoke('attr', 'src')
      .then((audiofile) => {
        const audio = new Audio(audiofile);
        audio.play();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.wait(1).then(_=>{
    new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_1.mp3').play();
})
```